# FX Request: Screen doors

Tags: effects, sound-effects-recording, request

So i'm a bit stuck at the moment in an ultra low budget feature i'm working on. I need an exterior screen door (with wood frame) opening, closing, and some creaking. If it's one that has a slow-closing mechanism of some kind, that would be even better. My problem with library FX here is that you generally get 1 open and 1 close, so if the door's used more than once it's more or less useless. That and, the Sound Ideas effect is too big and brutal for what i'm after.

My library is still rather undeveloped, so i don't have a huge amount to offer in return. I've got about an hour of stereo int strong gusty wind through a slightly open window; pretty cool for atmos beds. And i'm planning on buying a Zoom H4N very soon if a NYC specific effect would sweeten the deal.

Cheers!

Comment: Once again I feel like the ugly duckling finding my long-lost family. I love this site.

Comment: Getting all warm and fuzzy mid winter!

Answer (score 2):

Hi Roger - I may have something you could use. Get in touch with me via Linked In.

Comment: Great, thanks Jay!
I've had to add you as a contact on there, so i can message you without having to get a paid membership.

Answer (score 1):

Hey Roger, I've got some recent screen door recordings I did in North Carolina for Tim Prebble's door library. Let me know if you're interested.

Comment: @Joel Sounds good! Drop me a message on facebook or linkedin; i'm easy to find. And if i end up using it, i'll commit to buying the library once my next invoice comes in. In fact i'll probably buy it anyway, can never have enough doors...

Answer (score 0):

Any of these help? Many of these samples can be used commercially.

http://freesound.org/search/?q=screen+door

Comment: be careful with freesound.org. Frank Bry has found some of his sound effects up there, and those are definitely commercial effects that do not belong on the site. also, the site stipulates credit for the user who posted/created the sound effects. that's not always feasible on professional projects (where producers control the credit list).

Comment: I know that there are many attribution licenses, but didn't know about people finding their sounds up there, that's no good.

Comment: +1 @Shaun. Didn't know that (about Frank et al)!  Good to know though, thanks for the tip!